Endpoint with authorize attribute returns 200 and 401 code in turn
I did the cookie based authentication in my ASP.NET Core project and here is code:
Configuration
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, SessionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(u =>
{
    u.AddPolicy("ValidSession", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new SessionRequirement()));

    u.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddRequirements(new SessionRequirement())
        .Build();
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(u =>
    {
        u.SlidingExpiration = true;
        u.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        u.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        u.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        u.LoginPath = string.Empty;
        u.AccessDeniedPath = string.Empty;
        u.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = v =>
        {
            v.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        u.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

...

app.ConfigureRequestLocalization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.AddHealthCheckEndpoints();
app.UseEndpoints(u => u.MapControllers());
app.UseSwaggerPersonUI(provider);

Assign cookie
var session = await _authService.AuthenticateViaIdm(authCodeInfo.Code, state.UniqueState);

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new(ClaimTypes.Authentication, session.Id.ToString()),
    //TODO: add username, id, role
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    ExpiresUtc = session.ExpirationDate,
    IssuedUtc = session.CreateDate,
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

A custom authorization requirement
public class SessionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<SessionRequirement>
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;


    public SessionHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        ;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SessionRequirement requirement)
    {
        var sessionIdClaim = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Authentication);

        if (sessionIdClaim == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            Log.Information("Session claim is not found");
            return;
        }

        if (Guid.TryParse(sessionIdClaim.Value, out var sessionId))
        {
            Log.Information("Session claim is parsed");

            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var sessionOperator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthSessionOperator>(); 
            var isValidSession = await sessionOperator.IsValid(sessionId);
            if(isValidSession)
            {
                Log.Information("Session claim is valid");
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return;
            }
            
        }
        
        context.Fail();
    }
}

The endpoint
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("isAuthenticated")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public ActionResult<string> IsAuthenticated() => Ok("You're authenticated");

The problem is that the endpoint returns 200 and 401 code in turn. Also I know that happens because Http.Context.User.Claims is empty(I see "Session claim is not found" in logs) and I don't see it when the endpoints return 200 code. The situation happens only on a test env, not on a dev.
PS: The requests always contain auth cookie.

1)are you using load balancer?2)could you check cookie size 3)could you compare for appsettings.json, environment variables and check if any differences in configuration files 4) what is your ssl / TLS setting? 5)try to print all the claims and cookies in the logs to understand what is being received in the request.6)have you tried to test with different browser?

@JalpaPanchal I see auth cookie in every request, so that only Http.Context.User.Claims is empty sometimes. And I don't think that a middleware can cause this behavior. Thanks for ideas!

could you help answer these questions as well : could you check cookie size,  what is your ssl / TLS setting?, have you tried to test with different browser?
